# How can I write footer only in the last page in a qWeb report from Odoo?

Tags: html, odoo-11

I have written a qWeb report for Odoo11, it's length is variable. I need to write a footer but only in the last page of the report.

```
<odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="report_albaran">
            <t t-call="web.html_container">
                <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
                    <t t-call="web.external_layout">

                        <div class="page">
                            <table>Aqui escribo el contenido de mi report.........</table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="footer">Este es mi pie de página</div>
                    </t>
                </t>
            </t>
        </template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

I have try writing "footer>" in mi html program, so I have the footer in all pages. 
I will be gratefull if someome could help me.
Thanks,

Comment: Apply footer after the </t> then it will works.

Comment: Thanks Akshay. I have changed my code but it doesn't work. If I write the footer after the </t> it doesn't appear.

Comment: after docs </t> you have to write.